# How to add hostname as first line of a file

Tags: vi, hostname, editors, columns

I have a file which has a few lines.

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

I need to add hostname of the server I'm working on as the first line of the file.
For example if abcd555.india.com is the server, the output file should be like :

```
abcd555.india.com
one
two
three
four
five
```

Hope my question is clear! I would be grateful to anyone who helps me out in this hour of need.

Comment: It's easier for people that are willing to answer to test their solutions on the actual data that you have, rather than having to re-type things from an image. It may not matter much in this case, but for future reference, please copy and paste text, not images.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `vi` command

```
:0r !hostname
```

Or, in its longer form,

```
:0read !hostname
```

You would have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> first, of course.

The `read` command usually takes a filename and inserts the contents of that file beneath the current line, but if you specify a shell command with `!` in front of it, it will take the output from that command and insert *that* beneath the current line.

However, we don't just want to insert this anywhere. We want to insert it on the *first* line.  That's why we say `0r`.  The zero specifies the line number after which the command output (or file) will be placed.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work using `sed`?

Here assuming GNU `sed`:

`sed -i '1 i\'"$HOSTNAME" file`

Using this with a file named test1 produces:

```
$ cat test1
one
two
three
four
five
```

Then:

```
$ sed -i '1 i\'"$HOSTNAME" test1
```

leads to:

```
$ cat test1
chris-dell
one
two
three
four
five
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this programmatically is to write to a temporary file and then overwrite the existing one:

```
{ hostname; cat somefile; } > somefile.tmp &&
  mv somefile.tmp somefile
```

Comment: This is sensitive to race conditions. If someone makes another change to `somefile` between your first line and your second line, you've just lost an edit.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst the sed examples do the same thing, just more transparently.

Comment: the major difference between the sed examples and this one is that the `sed` examples use `sed`'s `-i` parameter, which makes it an *atomic* operation. For that reason, they don't have the race condition your suggestion does have.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst it is not atomic. Sed creates a temporary file with the new contents and then moves it, just like this `bash` example. You can see this via strace. Same with `perl`'s "in place" editing.

Comment: Turns out you're right. I stand corrected. Unfortunately I can't fix my vote apparently, unless an edit is done first. wtf? ah well.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged `vi` however it sounds like you're looking for a CLI option. While in `vi` you can use `shift + O` to insert above and automatically add a new line and just paste your line right in. If you don't want to use an editor you can use `sed` (here assuming the GNU implementation).

```
sudo sed -i '1iabcd555.india.com' /etc/hosts
```